# Can I/How do I access client side cookies through a websocket connection to a twisted app?

Tags: python, cookies, websocket, twisted

i have a simple twisted application, with the websockets module. the application is serving a lineReceiver protocol, and i'd like to inspect the contents of incoming connections, including seeing which cookies are set on them, something like this:

```
class Echo(basic.lineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Got new client!"
        #print request.cookies
```

is it possible for me to access request (client-side) cookies from a protocol that's served over websockets? if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_httpheaders) that includes a WebSocket client and a server that set/get custom HTTP headers. Adapting this you can access cookies sent by e.g. a browser during the initial WebSocket opening handshake on server-side.

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.